# libcurl function symbols not found in x86_64 architecture

Tags: c, curl, terminal

im trying to make a libcurl program that connects to an https website but when i use the functions like curl_easy_setopt(); the terminal says that the symbols are invalid in x86_64 architecture. heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
CURL *curl;
char buffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
int main(void) {
    if ((curl = curl_easy_init()) != NULL) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sourceforge.net/");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, buffer);
        if (curl_easy_perform(curl) != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buffer);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and heres the gcc:

```
cd "/Users/rowan/Desktop/web scraper/" && gcc scrape.c -o scrape && "/Users/rowan/Desktop/web scraper/"scrape
```

im using macOS if that helps

Comment: Please edit your question and post your `gcc` commands in a separate code block

Comment: Also, please add the output of your build in another code block. And, what OS/distro are you using (e.g. linux/ubuntu)? Are you sure you've installed the correct 64 bit libraries [vs. just the 32 bit versions]?